# how to deploy openwhisk on kubernets on PIs 4

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, serverless, openwhisk

i'm trying to deploy openwhisk flowing the official documentation I do have one master and 2 workers where one is as core and the other is invoker however when I deeply using helm

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube.git
helm install owdev ./helm/openwhisk -n openwhisk --create-namespace -f mycluster.yaml
```

[image]

however no package is correctly running
[image]

Comment: To deploy openwhisk on kubernetes , Please refer to this [document](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do below things

As per  [Readme page](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/README.md)

- You will need at least 1 worker node with 4GB of memory and 2 virtual CPUs to deploy the default configuration of OpenWhisk.
- Make sure you label the worker nodes

> kubectl label node <worker-node-name>  openwhisk-role=invoker

- Your worker node should be able to pull open whisk images from the docker repository